# JPA custom query involving foreign_key

Tags: java, jpa

I would like to make a JPA query to count how many records are with a specific foreign key.

Entities:

```
@Entity(name = "person")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person {

  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String phoneNumber;
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
  @JoinColumn(name = "ADRESS_FK")
  private ADDRESS address;
}


@Entity(name = "address")
public class Address {

  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String country;
  private String city;
  private String street;
  private String number;
}
```

And this is what i am trying, how would this look in JPA?

```
public Long getOccurences( Long id ) {
  Query query = _entityManager.createQuery( "Select count(*) from Persons p where p.address = ?1" );
  query.setParameter( 1, id );
  return query.getSingleResult() );
```

}

Comment: Did you try with `WHERE p.address.id = ?1`? I guess it should work.

Comment: I would guess the same, plus you probably also want to use `COUNT(p)` rather than the `*`.

Comment: public Long getOccurences( Long id ) {
  Query query = _entityManager.createQuery( "Select * from Persons p where p.address = ?" );
  query.setParameter( 1, id );
  return query.getResultList().size());